# Converting struct to byte and back to struct

Tags: c++, struct, byte, arduino, xbee

I'm currently working with [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno)s, 9DOFs, and [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee)s, and I was trying to create a struct that could be sent over serial, byte by byte, and then re-constructed into a struct.

So far I have the following code:

```
struct AMG_ANGLES {
    float yaw;
    float pitch;
    float roll;
};

int main() {
    AMG_ANGLES struct_data;

    struct_data.yaw = 87.96;
    struct_data.pitch = -114.58;
    struct_data.roll = 100.50;

    char* data = new char[sizeof(struct_data)];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<sizeof(struct_data); i++){
        // cout << (char*)(&struct_data+i) << endl;
        data[i] = (char*)(&struct_data+i); //Store the bytes of the struct to an array.
    }

    AMG_ANGLES* tmp = (AMG_ANGLES*)data; //Re-make the struct
    cout << tmp.yaw; //Display the yaw to see if it's correct.
}
```

Source: http://codepad.org/xMgxGY9Q

This code doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

How do I solve this?

Comment: a plead to all c++ programmers - use c++ style casts instead of c-style casts.

Comment: Didn't realize they were c-style casts as this is what my teachers taught my in my C++ class

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It seems I've solved my issue with the following code.

```
struct AMG_ANGLES {
    float yaw;
    float pitch;
    float roll;
};

int main() {
    AMG_ANGLES struct_data;

    struct_data.yaw = 87.96;
    struct_data.pitch = -114.58;
    struct_data.roll = 100.50;

    //Sending Side
    char b[sizeof(struct_data)];
    memcpy(b, &struct_data, sizeof(struct_data));

    //Receiving Side
    AMG_ANGLES tmp; //Re-make the struct
    memcpy(&tmp, b, sizeof(tmp));
    cout << tmp.yaw; //Display the yaw to see if it's correct
}
```

WARNING: This code will only work if sending and receiving are using the same [endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) architecture.

Comment: An addition to your warning, both sides need to represent a float identically as well.  I'd recommend sending it as fixed point integer (in your example above: 8796, -11458, 10050) and document the endianness of the values.  Use functions like `htobe32()` from `endian.h` to convert between host and big- or little-endian.

Comment: @Steven10172 Couldn't the struct have padding?  This would not tightly pack the structure.

Answer (score 7):

You do things in the wrong order, the expression

```
&struct_data+i
```

takes the address of `struct_data` and increases it by `i` *times the size of the structure*.

Try this instead:

```
*((char *) &struct_data + i)
```

This converts the address of `struct_data` to a `char *` and *then* adds the index, and then uses the dereference operator (unary `*`) to get the "char" at that address.

Comment: It doesn't seem to let me call it. I get "Line 23: error: request for member 'yaw' in 'tmp', which is of non-class type 'AMG_ANGLES*'"

Comment: See my answer. You have to use '->'

Comment: This has helped a lot right now, 6 years later. Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 4):

Always utilize data structures to its fullest..

```
union AMG_ANGLES {
  struct {
    float yaw;
    float pitch;
    float roll;
  }data;
  char  size8[3*8];
  int   size32[3*4];
  float size64[3*1];
};
```

Comment: Why is float 8 bytes long?

Comment: it's not. float is 32bit. But there is double, which is basically just a 64bit float. Also there is long double.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<sizeof(struct_data); i++){
    // +i has to be outside of the parentheses in order to increment the address
    // by the size of a char. Otherwise you would increment by the size of
    // struct_data. You also have to dereference the whole thing, or you will
    // assign an address to data[i]
    data[i] = *((char*)(&struct_data) + i); 
}

AMG_ANGLES* tmp = (AMG_ANGLES*)data; //Re-Make the struct
//tmp is a pointer so you have to use -> which is shorthand for (*tmp).yaw
cout << tmp->yaw; 
}
```

Comment: What solution would be more efficient? Yours or mine? This operation will be running ~30-50 times a second

Comment: memcpy is probably more efficient. So, I would go with your solution. It also makes the code easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why I would have to use -> I've still new to C++, only started to learn 2-3months ago, and all the *'s and &'s still confuse me sometimes

Comment: yup, pointers are a classic hurdle C and C++ beginners have to clear. As to why memcpy is more efficient, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209529/optimized-memcpy)