# Possible to convert std::vector of std::pairs into a byte array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, casting

I am wondering if it is possible to convert vector of pairs into a byte array.

Here's a small example of creating the vector of pairs:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PBYTE FileData, FileData2, FileData3;
    DWORD FileSize, FileSize2, FileSize3;

    /* Here I read 3 files + their sizes and fill the above variables. */

    //Here I create the vector of std::pairs.
    std::vector<std::pair<PBYTE, DWORD>> DataVector
    {
        { FileData, FileSize }, //Pair contains always file data + file size.
        { FileData2, FileSize2 },
        { FileData3, FileSize3 }
    };

    std::cin.ignore(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to convert this vector into a byte array (for compressing, and writing to disk, etc)?

Here is what I tried, but I didn't get even the size correctly:

```
PVOID DataVectorArr = NULL;

DWORD DataVectorArrSize = DataVector.size() * sizeof DataVector[0];

if ((DataVectorArr = malloc(DataVectorArrSize)) != NULL)
{
    memcpy(DataVectorArr, &DataVector[0], DataVectorArrSize);
}

std::cout << DataVectorArrSize;

//... Here I tried to write the DataVectorArr to disk, which obviously fails because the size isn't correct. I am not also sure if the DataVectorArr contains the DataVector now.

if (DataVectorArr != NULL) delete DataVectorArr;
```

Enough code. Is is it even possible, or am I doing it wrong? If I am doing it wrong, what would be the solution?

Regards, Okkaaj

Edit: If it's unclear what I am trying to do, read the following (which I commented earlier):

Yes, I am trying to cast the vector of pairs to a `PCHAR` or `PBYTE` - so I can store it to disk using WriteFile. After it is stored, I can read it from disk as byte array, and parse back to vector of pairs. Is this possible? I got the idea from converting / casting `struct` to a byte array and back(read more from here: [Converting struct to byte and back to struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775893/converting-struct-to-byte-and-back-to-struct)) but I am not sure if this is possible with std::vector instead of structures.

Comment: Shall this byte array be a contiguous region of all pairs described in  your pair-vector, in order?

Comment: `sizeof DataVector[0]` will give you the same as `sizeof(std::pair<PBYTE, DWORD>)` which probably isn't what you want here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'size is not correct'? What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: @user2040251 I am getting 24 bytes as the size, which cannot be true when I have read bytes of 3 files into the vector. I am expecting a size of 3 files + size of the DWORDS (FileSize1, etc) and the size of the vector. Sorry if this is a bad explanation, I am very tired...

Comment: it's a bit unclear what you're really trying to achieve. do you want the contents of the tree files concatenated and stored somewhere?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Exactly. Yes, I am trying to cast the vector of pairs to a `PCHAR` or `PBYTE` - so I can store it to disk using WriteFile. After it is stored, I can read it from disk as byte array, and parse back to vector of pairs. Is this possible? I got the idea from converting / casting `struct` to a byte array and back(read more from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775893/converting-struct-to-byte-and-back-to-struct) but I am not sure if this is possible with std::vector instead of structures.

Comment: If you want code to convert some data structure into an array of characters or bytes, why don't you write some code to do that? Decide on a format, document it, and then write code that actually does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `malloc` and make use of RAII for this:

```
std::vector<BYTE> bytes;
for (auto const& x : DataVector)
    bytes.insert(bytes.end(), x.first, x.first+x.second);

// bytes now contains all images buttressed end-to-end.
std::cout << bytes.size() << '\n';
```

To avoid potential resize slow-lanes, you can enumerate the size calculation first, then `.reserve()` the space ahead of time:

```
std::size_t total_len = 0;
for (auto const& x : DataVector)
    total_len += x.second;

std::vector<BYTE> bytes;
bytes.reserve(total_len);
for (auto const& x : DataVector)
    bytes.insert(bytes.end(), x.first, x.first+x.second);

// bytes now contains all images buttressed end-to-end.
std::cout << bytes.size() << '\n';
```

But if all you want to do is dump these contiguously to disk, then why not simply:

```
std::ofstream outp("outfile.bin", std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
for (auto const& x : DataVector)
    outp.write(static_cast<const char*>(x.first), x.second);
outp.close();
```

skipping the middle man entirely.

And honestly, unless there is a good reason to do otherwise, it is *highly* likely your DataVector would be better off as simply a `std::vector< std::vector<BYTE> >` in the first place.

---

**Update**

If *recovery* is needed, you can't just do this as above. The minimal artifact that is missing is the description of the data itself. In this case the description is the actual *length* of each pair segment. To accomplish that the length must be stored along with the data. Doing that is trivial unless you also need it portable to platform-independence.

If that last sentence made you raise your brow, consider the problems with doing something as simple as this:

```
std::ofstream outp("outfile.bin", std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
for (auto const& x : DataVector)
{
    uint64_t len = static_cast<uint64_t>(x.first);
    outp.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&len), sizeof(len));
    outp.write(static_cast<const char*>(x.first), x.second);
}
outp.close();
```

Well, now you can read each file by doing this:

- Read a `uint64_t` to obtain the byte length of the data to follow
- Read the data of that length

But this has inherent problems. It isn't portable at all. The endian-representation of the reader's platform had better match that of the writer, or this is utter fail. To accommodate this limitation the *length* preamble must be written in a platform-independent manner, which is tedious and a foundational reason why serialization libraries and their protocols exit in the first place.

If you haven't second-guessed what you're doing and how you're doing it by this point, you may want to read this again.

Comment: @WhozCraig: it's not at all clear that the OP wants the concatenation of the contents of the three files. at least to me. as I see it sounds like some XY problem: real problem X, asking for implementation problem with imagined solution Y, where Y is not necessarily meaningful as a solution to X.

Comment: What's the point of writing data this way if you can't read it back properly?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I concur. Why anyone would do this is beyond me, but it is none-the-less doable (obviously). I would surmise a serialization library (or at least a sound protocol and hand-rolled code on both sides to enforce it) would be what is *really* needed, but with the OP's stated desire its hard saying. If compression were the end-game, why not use a zip-format-wrapped zlib implementation, for example (which is readily available to the masses). I'm thinking you're likely right, that the *real* problem will still surface once this nuance is deployed.