# Can I change the value of something in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm very new to assembly in fact I just started learning today and I am trying to figure out a way to change a value stored in .data to something else in the _start: area of the code. I have tried several ways to do this but I can't seem to figure it out. I do get 2 errors:

```
main.asm:5: warning: character constant too long
main.asm:5: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

Code:

```
section .text
    global _start       
_start:                  

    ;where the issue starts
    mov msg, 'Hello, world.' ; i want to change the value to hello world with a . instead of a !
    mov edx, len    ;message length
    mov ecx, msg    ;message to write
    mov ebx, 1      ;stdout
    mov eax, 4      ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel
    
    mov eax, 1      ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

section .data

msg db  'Hello, world!',0xa ;The original string
len equ $ - msg         ;string length
```

Comment: You can't write to a label. The destination of `mov` must be a memory reference (in brackets `[...]`) or a single register. You also cannot write an entire string, you have to decompose it into manageable chunks. (Traditionally, 1 byte, though you can work with two-byte or four-byte chunks too.)

Comment: To change one byte in msg, do something like  `mov [msg+12], al`

Comment: what if i wanted to change all the bytes

Comment: Then you need `movs`

Comment: how would i go about using movs

Comment: More generally, to change all the bytes, you write a whole bunch of `mov` instructions, or you write a loop.  `rep movsb` is useful if the desired contents are elsewhere in memory and need to be copied without change, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804852/assembly-rep-movs-mechanism/43845229#43845229.

Comment: i'm still very confused

Comment: Strings aren't "first class" objects in asm.  They're just arrays of chars.  You can't `mov` a whole array, only at most 4 bytes with a single `mov` in 32-bit mode, e.g. a pointer.  e.g. you can do `mov word [msg], "xy"` to update the first 2 bytes of the array at `msg:`.